# How to update OSM data, without recreating the PostGIS database?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, osmosis

We are currently working with GeoServer and PostGis which stores the OSM data for Switzerland.

I would like to know, how to update the OSM data for my GeoServer. At my current level of knowledge, I would need to download the diff file than update the pbf file with osmosis after that I would have to create a new database for the new data and import it again.

With this method, I would need to reaply all configuration on my GeoServer again from the beginning.

Is there an easier way to update my OSM data?

Comment: `osm2pgsql --append`?

Comment: I have seen this option too, but I am not sure how it works. Can you give me further information how the append option is working?

Comment: If you can show how you did the import, and what you've tried with `--append` so far, perhaps we can help.

Comment: If I am allowed to be honest, I haven't tried to update now. I am only seeking for information, before I update the customers database. Therefore I would appreciate to hear your expertise.